# Flutter Firestore Ordering Issues

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Flutter so please bear with me. So I need to fetch a User object from Firestore immediately once I hit the home page. The problem is that currently, I am attempting to fetch the User in the initState() function and the build function (which needs the user object) is triggered before the User object is fetched, causing an exception.

Here is my User fetching code in initState()

```
//get user object
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .document(widget.uid)
      .snapshots(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    setState(() {
      user = snapshot.data.data as User;
    });

  },
);
```

ALSO, I just figured out that this code doesn't ever get to the setState block. Don't know why. I know the stream Firestore ref is correct. Any recommendations on how to re-organize my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use stream builder as a widget immediately inside builds function.

```
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .document(widget.uid)
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            return Text(snapshot.data.data.userName); // example
      },
    );
```

Comment: If I do that won't it have to rebuild the streambuilders every time I have a slight update to the state?

Comment: I just tried this and it returns an error because the builder section never gets hit for some reason.